# How certain are we that and objects spacetime speed is constant

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, speed

I just recently realized - through the aid of a simple yet effective [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc) - that mass curves not space, but space**time**. This has lead me to finally understand why we use geodesics to explain the apparent acceleration of bodies toward massive objects. My current understanding is thus that the curvature of spacetime leads to a rotation of the spacetime velocity vector, "transferring" (I'm certain that this isn't kosher nomenclature) some of the temporal velocity component into a spatial velocity component.

For this to make sense I gather that the spacetime speed must be constant, as is also taught in special relativity. I wonder though if this is actually something we have tested? Have we gathered any empirical evidence for the constancy of the spacetime speed of an object? Is this even feasible to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have we gathered any empirical evidence for the constancy of the spacetime velocity of an object? Is this even feasible to test?

Yes, this is very feasible. The easiest manifestation of the constancy of the spacetime velocity is called time dilation. This has been experimentally tested from subatomic particles moving inertially to particles undergoing enormous accelerations in colliders to pieces of metal on rotors to macroscopic clocks on airplanes to clocks in satellites and even clocks just in labs. All of them have confirmed the relativistic prediction as described by the constancy of the spacetime velocity.

Answer (score 2):

> Have we gathered any empirical evidence for the constancy of the spacetime speed of an object?

In a way, the spacetime velocity is constant by definition. It is not really something to experimentally verify as an independent fact.

The spacetime velocity is defined as

$$v^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau},$$
where $x^\mu$ are coordinates you use and $\tau$ is proper time. To get the speed you need to take scalar product:
$$v^2=g_{\mu\nu}v^\mu v^\nu=\frac{g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu}{d\tau^2}$$

Now $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is spacetime interval along the spacetime trajectory. In your own frame, where you are at rest the only coordinate that changes along your motion is time your clocks show. The spacetime interval in rest frame is fully determined by the time you measure, which is in fact proper time. Thus the above formula really shows, that you are taking derivative of proper time w.r.t proper time. Usually the spacetime interval is measured in meters while proper time in seconds, so you need to include conversion factor, in this case the conversion factor is given by speed of light:

$$v^2=\frac{g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu}{d\tau^2}=\frac{ds^2}{d\tau^2}=c^2\frac{d\tau^2}{d\tau^2}=c^2$$

I am using signature of the metric (+,-,-,-).

There is no physics hidden in the claim (assuming relativity is correct of course), that spacetime speed is constant. It is direct consequence of definition of spacetime velocity. When you experimentally verify that spacetime velocity is constant, you are not really verifying this single fact, you are verifying theory of relativity itself. You are verifying, that time dilation and length contraction work as advertised.

> My current understanding is thus that the curvature of spacetime leads to a rotation of the spacetime velocity vector

Strictly speaking it does not. The geodesic is straight line, there is no rotation involved. The rotation you see in the video is for the sake of visualization. If the spacetime would be embedded in some higher dimensional flat space, then there would be rotation of the vector wrt this higher dimensional space, that is true. But this would depend on the particular embedding and it is not what GR says.

When you are standing on the surface of the Earth, you see freely falling object to accelerate. But this is not what is truly happening. In fact, it is you who is accelerated by the surface of the Earth and it is your spacetime velocity vector that is rotating, not the velocity vector of the falling object.

It is not curvature that rotates the velocity vector, it is your acceleration that rotates it. The curvature only tells you what kind of movements through spacetime are undergoing acceleration and what kind of movements are straight. The nonzero curvature only means, that your idea of standing on the surface of the Earth as straight path through the spacetime is faulty one and that you need to accelerate to keep traveling on it (this is also not fully correct. Curvature tells you that two initially parallel straight lines might actually converge or diverge, they need not remain parallel. It is connection, or [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) which determines what is a straight path (geodesics) and what is not)